# How do I get rid of this wireframe on my object?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

My low poly log cabin has a strange wireframe showing through the solid view making it difficult to select certain faces without selecting ones behind it.

[image]

Comment: .. but first .. click  'Limit Selection to Visible' .. just to the right of your Face Select icon in the header.

Comment: @RobinBetts You can see in the picture it already is clicked.

Comment: @RayMairlot   It would be blue if it was clicked? The default is see-through? (Which has always seemed a bit odd, to me..)